# App close event in Ionic Windows 8.1 App?

Tags: windows, cordova, ionic3

I'm building a Windows 8.1 App using Ionic 3. In the app, the user would have to type in a  lot of stuff. I want to avoid accidental closure of the app by clicking on 'X' button at the top right corner or by Alt+F4. When the user tries to close the app, is there a way to prevent the default behaviour of closing the app and instead ask a confirmation?

Answer (score 1):

You must override the [onbackbutton event](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html) to do this.

```
document.addEventListener('backbutton', function (evt) {
    /* BackButton pressed: do nothing */
    return;
}, false);
```

Do **NOT** use the method shown on that page to exit the app:

```
throw new Error('Exit'); // This will suspend the app BUT the store will reject it
```

If you do this to exit your app, it will be rejected by the Microsoft store. To exit the app, remove the event listener and let the backbutton event suspend the app normally.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I overrode the `onbackbutton event` as suggested and it doesn't fire when the user clicks the 'x' button to close the app. May be this event is intended only for 'Back' button press in Windows Phone 8?

Comment: It is intended for backbutton press on any device. I don't think it will be associated to the close button in Windows desktop platform. Remember to vote for useful replies.

Comment: Its useful, but it doesn't help in my case. I'm running the app on a Getac device where this no 'back' button and user would have to press the 'x' button to close the app.

Answer (score 0):

There's no special event to indicate that the user has closed an app.

App Lifecycle docs for Windows Store Apps.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/hh464925(v=win.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#app-close

When the user closes the app or moves the app to background, it enters into a Suspended State. Windows recommends saving user state when the app enters such a state. You can save data in that state thereby achieving the overall goal.